# How to find ec2 instances running under particular VPC using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-vpc

I am trying to create a script which does curl on one of my many instances running under a particular VPC ID.

Let say, I have VPC ID . Then how can i get the list of all ec2 instances running under this VPC and eventually how to find the particular ec2 instance named "test-ec2" . And then run a command eg. "curl  ip_address_of_test-ec2"

I have never used boto3, so do not know much about it.

Any suggestions what can be done to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [describe-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) and its `--filters` of `vpc-id` and `tag:key` for name.

For example, to get all instances ids in a given vpc:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=<your-vpc-id> \
  --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId' \
  --output text
```

Also to filter by name:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=<your-vpc-id> \
            Name=tag:Name,Values=<instance-name> \
  --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId' \
  --output text
```

In boto3, the equivalent function is [describe_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances):

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

r = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'vpc-id',
            'Values': ['<your-vpc-id>']
        },
        {
            'Name': 'tag:Name',
            'Values': ['<instance-name>']
        }  
    ])

for reservation in r['Reservations']:
  for instance in reservation['Instances']:
    private_ip_addr = instance['PrivateIpAddress']
    print(private_ip_addr)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again @Marcin, Need one more clarification: 

Will this be the right way to find out the ipaddress of the instance and then curl to it : 


`
ec2info = defaultdict()
for instance in r:
        ipaddress = instance[unicode('PrivateIpAddress')]
res = subprocess.check_output(['curl','ipaddress'])
print(res)
`

Comment: @Legitimate_Figure_4430 Difficult to say from comments, but why `curl`. You can use `requests` library or python's build in tools for querying urls. Also you need private ip address or public ip address?

Comment: 1. I need private ip address
2. One API is running on that EC2, so i want to basically curl on that. Any other way you can suggest to hit the api..
3. API URL will be like : http://ip_address/test

Comment: Thanks Marcin, I just wanna know why this : for reservation in r['Reservations']:..............2. What does this statement mean. And yes I will accept the answer. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Legitimate_Figure_4430 This is the form of response from [describe_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances). Please check `Response Syntax` in docs linked. `r['Reservations']` will access the outermost data structure in the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228291/discussion-between-legitimate-figure-4430-and-marcin).